# MySQL connection from web to local server in loop-like network

Tags: mysql, connection

My internet provider also got hosting services. So I buy a webhosting (for website) and one public IP to my own server (a physical machine in my company). Problem is that I can't connect to MySQL provided with hosting from my server and can't connect to MySQL on my server from website.
When I try from other computer to connect it working properly - I can connect to server database and to website database. I need to reconfigure something to connect from website to my server?

```
xxx.yyy.220.223 - my server
xxx.yyy.220.224 - website address
xxx.yyy.220.20 - my address on other machines (to connect internet)
```

Comment: Check firewall, and make sure that your MySQL user permissions allow connections from all hosts (Or the host that you're connecting from)

Comment: @FrankerZ I add a test code to connect in other website (from other provider) and I can connect to my server. Is it possible that the site is blocking access to the database on another server?